# Ajuda com formulario de email em etapas

Tags: php, session, email

Pessoal desculpa o incomodo, estou criando um formulário de email em 3 etapas com 3 paginas e cada uma é digitado dados no input, já li tutorial de session e não estou conseguindo imprimir no final os dados da primeira e da segunda pagina para mandar o email, o que eu colocaria em cada pagina para manter os dados ?

somente os dados da terceira pagina que é a ultima esta sendo enviado, gostaria que vocês me ajudassem, desde já, obrigado !

```html
PAGINA 1

<?php
session_start();

$nome = isset($_POST['nome']) ? $_POST['nome'] : '';
$_SESSION['nome'] = $nome;

$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$_SESSION['conta'] = $conta;

$telefone = isset($_POST['telefone']) ? $_POST['telefone'] : '';
$_SESSION['telefone'] = $telefone;

?>
<html>

<form method="POST" action="index2.php">
  <label>Nome</label>
  <input type="text" name="nome" maxlength="50" />
   <label>Email</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="50" />
 
  <label>Telefone</label>
  <input type="text" name="telefone" maxlength="50" />
 
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Proximo">
</form>

</html>


////

PAGINA 2

<?php
session_start();

$nome = isset($_POST['nome']) ? $_POST['nome'] : '';
$_SESSION['nome'] = $nome;

$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$_SESSION['conta'] = $conta;

$telefone = isset($_POST['telefone']) ? $_POST['telefone'] : '';
$_SESSION['telefone'] = $telefone;

$cidade = isset($_POST['cidade']) ? $_POST['cidade'] : '';
$_SESSION['cidade'] = $cidade;

$estado = isset($_POST['estado']) ? $_POST['estado'] : '';
$_SESSION['estado'] = $estado;

?>
<html>
<form method="post" action="index3.php">
 <label>Cidade</label>
  <input type="text" name="cidade" maxlength="50" />
  <label>Estado</label>
  <input type="text" name="estado" maxlength="50" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Proximo">
</html>

//

PAGINA 3

<?php
session_start();

$nome = isset($_POST['nome']) ? $_POST['nome'] : '';
$_SESSION['nome'] = $nome;

$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$_SESSION['conta'] = $conta;

$telefone = isset($_POST['telefone']) ? $_POST['telefone'] : '';
$_SESSION['telefone'] = $telefone;

$cidade = isset($_POST['cidade']) ? $_POST['cidade'] : '';
$_SESSION['cidade'] = $cidade;

$estado = isset($_POST['estado']) ? $_POST['estado'] : '';
$_SESSION['estado'] = $estado;

$msg = isset($_POST['msg']) ? $_POST['msg'] : '';
$_SESSION['msg'] = $msg;

?>
<html>
<form method="post" action="final.php">
 <label>Mensagem</label>
  <input type="text" name="msg" maxlength="50" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Enviar">
</html>


PAGINA 4


<?php
session_start();

$nome = isset($_POST['nome']) ? $_POST['nome'] : '';
$_SESSION['nome'] = $nome;

$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;

$telefone = isset($_POST['telefone']) ? $_POST['telefone'] : '';
$_SESSION['telefone'] = $telefone;

$cidade = isset($_POST['cidade']) ? $_POST['cidade'] : '';
$_SESSION['cidade'] = $cidade;

$estado = isset($_POST['estado']) ? $_POST['estado'] : '';
$_SESSION['estado'] = $estado;

$msg = isset($_POST['msg']) ? $_POST['msg'] : '';
$_SESSION['msg'] = $msg;

?>

<html>
 <label>nome: <?php echo "$nome"; ?> </label>
  <label>email: <?php echo "$email"; ?> </label>
   <label>telefone: <?php echo "$telefone"; ?> </label>
    <label>cidade: <?php echo "$cidade"; ?> </label>
     <label>estado: <?php echo "$estado"; ?> </label>
   <label>mensagem: <?php echo "$msg"; ?> </label>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Veja bem, uma `SESSION` pode ser utilizada por qualquer uma de suas páginas, desde que a mesma possua um `session_start()`.

O ponto é, você está setando um valor novo para as sessions em todas as suas páginas, dessa forma o valor que deveria ser passado é zerado na página seguinte. Editei seu código e estou apenas iniciando cada session uma vez e recuperando na última pagina:

---

**PÁGINA 1**

Esta página não precisa de `SESSION`, ela apenas cria o formulário e envia para a próxima.

```
<html>
    <form method="POST" action="index2.php">
        <label>Nome</label>
        <input type="text" name="nome" maxlength="50" />

        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="50" />

        <label>Telefone</label>
        <input type="text" name="telefone" maxlength="50" />

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Proximo">
    </form>
</html>
```

---

**PÁGINA 2**

Essa página deve pegar os dados iniciados na primeira e setar as `SESSIONS` correspondentes.

```
<?php

session_start();

$nome = isset($_POST['nome']) ? $_POST['nome'] : '';
$_SESSION['nome'] = $nome;

$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;

$telefone = isset($_POST['telefone']) ? $_POST['telefone'] : '';
$_SESSION['telefone'] = $telefone;

?>

<html>
    <form method="post" action="index3.php">
        <label>Cidade</label>
        <input type="text" name="cidade" maxlength="50" />

        <label>Estado</label>
        <input type="text" name="estado" maxlength="50" />

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Proximo">
    </form>
</html>
```

---

**PÁGINA 3**

Essa página deve pegar os dados iniciados e recebidos da segunda e setar as `SESSIONS` correspondentes.

```
<?php

session_start();

$cidade = isset($_POST['cidade']) ? $_POST['cidade'] : '';
$_SESSION['cidade'] = $cidade;

$estado = isset($_POST['estado']) ? $_POST['estado'] : '';
$_SESSION['estado'] = $estado;

?>

<html>
    <form method="post" action="final.php">
        <label>Mensagem</label>
        <input type="text" name="msg" maxlength="50" />

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Enviar">
    </form>
</html>
```

---

**PÁGINA 4**

Recupera o valor de todas as `SESSIONS`, lembrando que peguei o valor da variável `$msg` diretamente, pois não faz sentido iniciar uma `SESSION` para usar seu valor na própria página.

```
<?php

session_start();

$nome = $_SESSION['nome'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$telefone = $_SESSION['telefone'];
$cidade = $_SESSION['cidade'];
$estado = $_SESSION['estado'];
$msg = isset($_POST['msg']) ? $_POST['msg'] : '';

?>

<html>
    <label>nome: <?php echo "$nome"; ?> </label>
    <label>email: <?php echo "$email"; ?> </label>
    <label>telefone: <?php echo "$telefone"; ?> </label>
    <label>cidade: <?php echo "$cidade"; ?> </label>
    <label>estado: <?php echo "$estado"; ?> </label>
    <label>mensagem: <?php echo "$msg"; ?> </label>
</html>
```

Bom é isso, caso tenha alguma dúvida só perguntar

Att;

Comment: Que bom que pude ajudar, caso tenha resolvido mesmo seu problema, Marque como resposta.

Comment: Muito obrigado, testei aqui e deu certo, é que estou começando agora e não sabia dessa regra... ! errei aqui kkkk aokeoaeokae

Comment: marquei aqui, muito boa sua ajuda, to aprendendo aos poucos!

Comment: Amigo eu gostaria de saber como faço pra chegar tudo no email, porque eu estou colocando pra enviar e esta chegando tudo do mesmo jeito !

Comment: Que e-mail? precisaria ver a parte do código relacionado ao e-mail para poder dizer o que acontece. Mas se esta chegando tudo não esta correto?

Comment: não está chegando no email, porque inves de imprimir na pagina eu coloquei pra chegar no email... você tem email, pra eu te mandar é que não posso postar o codigo aqui :P

Comment: não precisa mais amigo, obrigado pela atenção, é que eu tinha esquecido do session_start();

Comment: @FleuquerLima no meu caso que uso checkbox e input e seleciono vários , como poderia fazer um formulário em duas etapa ? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/180263/como-fazer-formulario-em-etapas