# Como fazer formulario em etapas?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou criando um sistema e queria saber como fazer um formulário por etapa , ele funciona por checkbox e input e tipo só queria saber como passar os dados do primeiro formulário para o dois para ser inserido no mysql.

```html
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="280" bgcolor="#00BFFF">Refeição</td>
 <td width="70" bgcolor="#00BFFF">Quantidade</td>
 
    </tr>

 <tr>
  <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Costela de Tambaqui sem Espinha">Costela de Tambaqui sem Espinha</td>
  <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>
  
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Lombo de Tambaqui Frito sem Espinha">Lombo de Tambaqui Frito sem Espinha</td>
  <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>
 
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Caldeirada de Tambaqui sem Espinha">Caldeirada de Tambaqui sem Espinha</td>
  <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>

 
</table>
 <br>
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Proximo" name="Proximo"> 
</form>
```

E na pagina dois do formuário é esse de baixo mas no primeira etapa do formulário trabalho com checkbox e como vou selecionar vários deles terei que usar o implode para pegar todo os checkbox e input como poderia fazer ? Obrigado desde já

```
     if($_POST)
    {  
        $numero_mesa = $_POST['numero_mesa'];
        $pedido_refeicao = implode(', ', $_POST['pedido_refeicao']);
        $num_refeicao = implode(', ', $_POST['num_refeicao']);
}





<?php

session_start();

$nome = isset($_POST['nome']) ? $_POST['nome'] : '';
$_SESSION['nome'] = $nome;

$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;

$telefone = isset($_POST['telefone']) ? $_POST['telefone'] : '';
$_SESSION['telefone'] = $telefone;

?>
```

Comment: Você não precisa criar N formulários, basta dividir e fazer como as abas em *tab*. Submeteu o primeiro bloco, esconde esse e exibe o próximo... ao final quando der *submit*, o formulário completo será enviado.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript!

A ideia é como Papa Charlie respondeu no comentário da sua pergunta.

Pensei na seguinte proposta:

Etapa1 - Assim que o *imput* "submit/next" for acionado, event.preventDefault() não deixa que os dados sejam enviados, enquanto a etapa2 aparece na tela.

Etapa2 - Já na etapa2, assim que acionar "send", os dados são enviados via POST com Fetch API (ou qualquer outra maneira que você desejar).

O restante é com vocês.

```js
(function () {

const form = document.getElementById('form');
const etapa1 = document.getElementById('etapa1');
const etapa2 = document.getElementById('etapa2');
const URL = ""; //colocar a url desejada
        
form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  submit(this)//recuperar dados enviados
  .then(trocarEtapa) //trocar a div do form
  .then(post)//enviar dados
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
});
        
async function submit(context) {
  const formData = new FormData(context);
  return formatFormData(formData);
}

function trocarEtapa(data){
     etapa1.style.display = "none"; //esconder etapa1
     etapa2.style.display = "block"; //mostrar etapa2
     return data;
}
    
function post(data) {
    document.getElementById('btn-send').addEventListener('click', function () {
        fetch(URL, 
            {
               method: 'POST',
               headers: {
                           'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
               },
               body: 'json=' + JSON.stringify(data)
            }
       ).then(response => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
            } else if (response.status === 403)
                console.log('Access denied');
              else if (response.status === 404)
                console.log('Page not found');
              else if (response.status === 503)
                console.log('Be right back');
        });
   });
          
 })(document);
```

```html
<form id="form"> 
   
        <div id="etapa1"> 
             <input class="btn" id="submit" type="submit" value="Next" name="Next">
        </div> 
             
        <div id="etapa2" style="display: none;">
             <input class="btn" id="btn-send" type="button" value="Send" name="Send">
        </div>
        
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a variável SESSION[ ] do PHP

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_POST['Proximo1'])){
    $_SESSION["v1"] = "xx";
    $_SESSION['refeicao'] = $_POST['refeicao'];
}
if(isset($_POST['Proximo2'])){
    $_SESSION["v2"] = "xx";
    $_SESSION['refeicao1'] = $_POST['refeicao1'];
}
?>
<form action=""  method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="280" bgcolor="#00BFFF">Refeição</td>
            <td width="70" bgcolor="#00BFFF">Quantidade</td>
        </tr>

        
        <tr>
            <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Caldeirada">Caldeirada</td>
            <td width="20"><input type="text" name="refeicao" size="15"></td>
            <td><input class="btn" type="submit" value="Proximo" name="Proximo1"></td>
    </table>
</form>
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION["v1"])) {
    ?>
    <form action=""  method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <h3><?php echo $_SESSION['refeicao']; ?></h3>
                <td width="280" bgcolor="#00BFFF">Refeição</td>
                <td width="70" bgcolor="#00BFFF">Quantidade</td>
            </tr>

            
            <tr>
                <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Caldeirada">Caldeirada de Tambaqui </td>
                <td width="20"><input type="text" name="refeicao1" size="15"></td>
                <td><input class="btn" type="submit" value="Proximo" name="Proximo2"></td>
        </table>
    </form>
    <?php
}
if(isset($_SESSION["v2"])) {
    ?>
    <form action=""  method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <h3><?php echo $_SESSION['refeicao1']; ?></h3>
                <td width="280" bgcolor="#00BFFF">Refeição</td>
                <td width="70" bgcolor="#00BFFF">Quantidade</td>
            </tr>

            
            <tr>
                <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Caldeirada">Caldeirada de Tambaqui sem Espinha</td>
                <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>
                <td><input class="btn" type="submit" value="Proximo" name="Proximo"></td>
        </table>
    </form>
    <?php
    session_destroy();

}
```

Answer (score -3):

Não sei se é isso que você quer, mas acho que você tem que abrir um `form` da seguinte maneira:

> Aonde está escrito `formulario2` seria sua pagina em PHP que você criou para dar um `insert` no MySQL com o PHP.

```
<form action="formulario2.php"  method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="280" bgcolor="#00BFFF">Refeição</td>
            <td width="70" bgcolor="#00BFFF">Quantidade</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Costela de Tambaqui sem Espinha">Costela de Tambaqui sem Espinha</td>
            <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Lombo de Tambaqui Frito sem Espinha">Lombo de Tambaqui Frito sem Espinha</td>
            <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Caldeirada de Tambaqui sem Espinha">Caldeirada de Tambaqui sem Espinha</td>
            <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>
    </table>
    <br>
    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Proximo" name="Proximo"> 
</form>
```

Espero que seja isso que você está à procura! Abraços e boa sorte.